# How to use IHttpContextAccessor in static class to set cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a generic `addReplaceCookie` method in a static class. The method would look something like this

```
public static void addReplaceCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue)
{

    if ((HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies(cookieName) == null))
    {
        // add cookie
        HttpCookie s = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
        s.Value = cookieValue;
        s.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(s);
    }
    else {
        // ensure cookie value is correct 
        HttpCookie existingSchoolCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies(cookieName);
        existingSchoolCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
        existingSchoolCookie.Value = cookieValue;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(existingSchoolCookie);
    }

}
```

I know that in order to get the `HttpContext` in asp.net core you have to use the `IHttpContextAccessor`. But I cannot inject it into a static class.

Is there another way to get access to it?

I am using rc1-final.

Comment: Since it is a static class then you can create an initialize method that takes the interface and pass it in during setup of your services collection.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

While i would advise staying away from static class scenarios like this, it is still possible to achieve what you are asking for.

Assuming a static class like...

```
public class MyStaticHelperClass {
    private static IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    public static void SetHttpContextAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor  accessor) {
        httpContextAccessor = accessor;
    }

    public static void addReplaceCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue) {
        var HttpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies(cookieName) == null) {
            // add cookie
            HttpCookie s = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
            s.Value = cookieValue;
            s.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(s);
        } else {
            // ensure cookie value is correct 
            HttpCookie existingSchoolCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies(cookieName);
            existingSchoolCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
            existingSchoolCookie.Value = cookieValue;
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(existingSchoolCookie);
        }
    }
}
```

You would add the accessor in `Startup.ConfigureServices` since it is no longer added automatically

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection service) {

    //Register IHttpContextAccessor and its implementation.
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
    services.AddMvc();

    //...
}
```

And get the service via injection into the `Startup.Configure` method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
{
    MyStaticHelperClass.SetHttpContextAccessor(accessor);

    //...

}
```

Now with that done. I would still strongly advise converting your static class into a service whose concrete implementation would use the `IHttpContextAccessor` as a dependency that can be injected via its constructor.

```
public interface ICookieService {
    void AddReplaceCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue);
}

public class CookieService : ICookieService {
    IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    public CookieService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    public void AddReplaceCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue) {
        var HttpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies(cookieName) == null) {
            // add cookie
            HttpCookie s = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
            s.Value = cookieValue;
            s.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(s);
        } else {
            // ensure cookie value is correct 
            HttpCookie existingSchoolCookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies(cookieName);
            existingSchoolCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);
            existingSchoolCookie.Value = cookieValue;
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(existingSchoolCookie);
        }
    }
}
```

...that could then be registered with the Services collection...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection service) {

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    services.AddTransient<ICookieService, CookieService>();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

...and be available for injection into classes that have need of it's use.

```
public class SomeClassThatNeedCookieServicesController : Controller {
    ICookieService cookieService;

    public SomeClassThatNeedCookieServicesController(ICookieService cookieService) {
        this.cookieService = cookieService;
    }

    //...
}
```

This is how I do it to manage session cookies in my applications.

Comment: Awesome, I think Im starting to get it. Do you know, is there a way to replace a cookie in asp.net core, or does append automatically replace it?

Comment: What do you mean by append? I'm not sure I understand. I normally use the `Response.Cookies.Set(cookie)` if that is what you mean. where the cookie has the key and value(s).

Comment: Yea, for some reason Response.Cookies.Set is throwing an error for me. I have to use Response.Cookies.Append(cookieName, cookieValue, CookieOption); But thats fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: would you please describe why you don`t recommend static class for this scenarios and what is the scenarios you recommend for it?

Comment: shouldnt singleton be used instead of transient for httpcontextaccessor

Answer (score 4):

If possible, don't use `static class`. But if you have to use, sending `IHttpContextAccessor` as a parameter might be a solution.

```
public static void addReplaceCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
{
   //your code
}
public class CallerClass
{
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

   public CallerClass(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
   {
       _accessor = accessor;
       addReplaceCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, accessor);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

later in Startup.Configure add by DI IServiceProvider and use it to extract IHttpContextAccessor like this:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider svp)
    {
        IHttpContextAccessor accessor = svp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        MyRepository.SetHttpContextAccessor(accessor);
```