# IHttpContextAccessor always get null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with .net5 using MVC. I'm trying to get httpcontext in a view using this class below, but I'm getting null at IHttpContextAccessor (_http), dont know why.

View side:

```
 @if (Checkout.Tools.Acesso.Permitido("admin"))
                        {
                            <li class="nav-main-heading">INFRA</li>
                            <li class="nav-main-item">
                                <a class="nav-main-link" href="/hangfire">
                                    <i class="nav-main-link-icon si si-refresh"></i>
                                    <span class="nav-main-link-name">Hangfire</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        }
```

Class side:

```
using Checkout.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Linq;

namespace Checkout.Tools
{
    public class Acesso
    {
        private static IHttpContextAccessor _http;

        public Acesso(IHttpContextAccessor http)
        {
            _http = http;
        }

        public static bool Permitido(string grupos)
        {
            string[] g = grupos.Split(",");
            return Permitido(g);
        }

        public static bool Permitido(string[] grupos)
        {
            var usuario = _http.HttpContext.Session.GetObject<Usuario>("usuario");
            string[] ugroups = usuario.Grupos.Split(",");
            string[] check = grupos.Intersect(ugroups).ToArray();
            return (check.Length != 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `private static IHttpContextAccessor _http;` is static... `IHttpContextAccessor http` in constructor can initialize `_http` only when constructor is called that means you need to create an object to call the constructor. Since you are directly calling `Permitido` method, constructor never gets called, that's why `_http` is null.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329354/how-to-use-ihttpcontextaccessor-in-static-class-to-set-cookies) help

Comment: You methods need to be non-`static` and you need to use an instance of `Acesso` in your code. Otherwise you're not going to be invoking the DI system.

Comment: Works fine based on this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37329354/how-to-use-ihttpcontextaccessor-in-static-class-to-set-cookies